# Android Service called twice

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I have one apps in that my service called twice so all task done two times i so much googling but can not find any thing i have same problem in finding a link (stackoverflow questions) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602926/android-service-called-automatically-so-mail-send-twice-repitedly please any know this how to do this and wts the solution.

Comment: post your code buddy.

Comment: you see the link i put

Comment: helo  @Spring Breaker  find anything ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602926/android-service-called-automatically-so-mail-send-twice-repitedly